# Loop completion and resetting

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Alright, so this code is for a game that is a power source connected to 6 buttons at ports 1, 2, 9, 11, 12, and 13. These are consequently supposed to light up 6 LEDs, each connected to 1. If you press the buttons in the right order, all the LEDs blink at once. Does it work?

```
int ledPin1 = 1;
int ledPin2 = 2;
int ledPin3 = 9;
int ledPin4 = 11;
int ledPin5 = 12;
int ledPin6 = 13;

void setup() {
//put your setup code here, to run once:
}
void loop() {
//put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
int QuestionNumberArray[] = {1, 2, 9, 11, 12, 13};//the array itself
const size_t n = sizeof(questionNumberArray) //the array used
sizeof(questionNumberArray[0]);//the base of the array

for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) //the loop itself
{
size_t j = random(1, n-i);
int t = questionNumberArray[i]; //integer output for increase
questionNumberArray[i] = questionNumberArray[j];//the value definition
questionNumberArray[j] = t;
pinMode(questionNumberArray, INPUT);
if(digitalRead(questionNumberArray) == HIGH) {
then(digitalRead(1, 2, 9, 11, 12, 13) == HIGH)
break; 
}
}
```

Also, how do I make it so that people have multiple tries to do it, or is it already like that?
Thank you

Comment: Hi err. I have reverted your last change that removed all contents of the question. Even when questions are put on hold, we leave its content as it was so it can be searched later.